# RDS amazon database - Not offering Subnet Group from ElastiCache

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-aurora-serverless

I've created a VPC. By default the VPC created one public and one private subnet. I've created an additional private subnet in a different availability zone.

I then (in the ElasticCache console) created a new subnet group that contains these two private subnets from the VPC. This subnet group is also associated, of course, with the VPC.

Then, on creating an Aurora RDS (create read replica) within this VPC, it asks for a subnet group. There's one there, a 'default' group, but my new subnet group doesn't appear.

How do I create a subnet group that is acceptable.

Comment: Did you create new subnet group for the new vpc?

Comment: ElastiCache subnet group is for ElastiCache.  If you want to define a subnet group for RDS instances, you'd do that in the RDS console not ElastiCache.